# Meteor publishing/subscribing to subset of collection

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to do a pub/sub for a chatroom function. What I need to do is, publish the subset of "Chatrooms" where it has field user1= current user id, or where it has field user2=current user id. So my code looks like this in coffeescript:

```
Meteor.publish "chatrooms1", publishFunction1 = ->
  Chatrooms.find
    user1: @userId

Meteor.publish "chatrooms2", publishFunction2 = ->
  Chatrooms.find
    user2: @userId
```

And in my subscription, I want it to only subscribe to chatrooms if the user is logged in:

```
Router.map () ->
  @route 'home',
  path: '/'

  waitOn: ->
    [
      Meteor.subscribe('users')
      Meteor.subscribe('instruments')
      Meteor.subscribe('instrumentList')
    ]
  if Meteor.user()
    waitOn: ->
      [
        Meteor.subscribe('chatrooms1')
        Meteor.subscribe('chatrooms2')
      ]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, the pub/sub doesn't really work so the page doesn't load.
After this step, I was going to try to make the if Meteor.user() in the sub part reactive, but that will come later.

Comment: Can you show the entire route? It's confusing as written.

Comment: okay I added the entire route!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is mostly a CoffeeScript problem - you can't have an `if` in the middle of an object literal like that (if ever in doubt, you can just paste the code into the 'try coffeesctipt' tab [here](http://coffeescript.org/)). The compiled code doesn't add the 2nd `waitOn` to your route. Give something like this a try:

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'home',
    path: '/'

    waitOn: ->
      subs = [
        Meteor.subscribe 'users'
        Meteor.subscribe 'instruments'
        Meteor.subscribe 'instrumentList'
      ]

      if Meteor.user()
        subs.push Meteor.subscribe 'chatrooms1'
        subs.push Meteor.subscribe 'chatrooms2'

      subs
```

Alternatively, you can simplify your chatroom publications down a single function:

```
Meteor.publish 'chatrooms', ->
  return @ready() unless @userId
  Chatrooms.find $or: [{user1: @userId}, {user2: @userId}]
```

Note how it immediately returns ready if the user isn't logged in. Then your route would be:

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'home',
    path: '/'

    waitOn: -> [
        Meteor.subscribe 'users'
        Meteor.subscribe 'instruments'
        Meteor.subscribe 'instrumentList'
        Meteor.subscribe 'chatrooms'
    ]
```

Comment: Okay I'll try those later on today. But I have a question, where is the $or and subs.push syntax from? Are they Mongoid syntax or part of iron-router? or Meteor?

Comment: `subs` is just an array of subscription handles - I'm just pushing two more handles onto it. [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) is a mongodb operator.